# ruby using session for restful requests and redirect_to

Tags: ruby, session, rest, redirect

I'm trying to get set my requests RESTful but i don't think i'm doing a good job at it.. here's what's i have, i want to always keep the params p1 and p2 from view in order to be RESTful:

In my controller:

```
  def index
    #if can't find p1 then grab from session and re-direct to make it a RESTful request
    #if not in session then it's a brand new call
    if params[:p1] == nil && session[:p1] != nil
      params[:p1] = session[:p1]
      redirect_to :action => "index", params[:p1] => session[:p1]
    else
      session[:p1] = params[:p1]
    end

   ... same as above but with p2 ...
```

I get the error of not two redirections can happen within the same action... so i try to combine it but then it keeps looping and the page will say that Ruby has identify that this request will never finish... is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." REST doesn't mean you have to keep redirecting until all values of interest are part of the actual request.

Comment: I never said that so your comment is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Your stated problem is due to cyclicly redirecting to the same, current action while attempting to append values to the query string from the session. You agreed in the comments below that the values you are interested in do not belong in the request at all, but more likely in the database. Where is the irrelevance in my comment?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use the `||=` operator in Ruby. That way you will not need the `if-else` fiasco that is going on in your code.

Try something like:

```
params[:p1] ||= session[:p1]
```

However, I'm not too sure what you meant when you said You want to make your actions more RESTful? I'll try to update my answer if you update your question with more insights and background that will give us some more context.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i'm new to ruby, didn't know there was such thing, will change it.. however problem still remains... by more RESTful i mean i want to have all the information i need in every request (hence why i need p1 and p2 to be available), since that's not always the case, because you're doing other actions on the website i'm using the session to add those and redict the call again with all the information.. does that make sense? thanks.

Comment: It seems your understanding of `REST` is a little flawed. REST clearly doesn't dictate that you have all your `params` persist between different requests. Infact, `REST` suggest a completely opposite approach. However, I would be interested to help you out and learn why you would like your params to persist between different requests? 

By definition of the HTTP protocol, that is just not possible because HTTP is a sessionless protocol. You can emulate that with `sessions` but then you'd be going against `REST` recommendations.

Comment: but isn't the whole notion of REST having all the information you need to perform your request without having to depend on anything else? I need to be able to persist user preference accross the session, so if they picked in the index page a checkbox, they can go back there after they went to other places in the website and the checkbox is still unchecked, i'd like to make that request restful.. have all those checkboxes (p1) selections available RESTfully... I'll take any advice i can get.

Comment: You are right in saying that `whole notion of REST is having all the information you need to perform your request without having to depend on anything else`

I'll re-phrase this: `REST recommends a pattern that a system be able to process a request without depending on any other request in the request universe`, so your request A should not be tied to request B in any manner - They should be decoupled.

If we bring into this discussion the approach you were taking, your approach beats the purpose of REST.

Comment: Agreed, so how do I accomplish this? that's what i was trying to do above... because without the session I won't be able to remember a user's options in a subsequent request, hence why i have to populate the request with the info saved previously in the session and redirect it with all that info hence making it RESTful in the redirection.

Comment: When the user selects options, they are changing the state of some object. These changes should lead to PUT/POST requests that change your back-end state. I wouldn't try to keep option selections in the session; read the options from the database. Keep the session as small as possible.

Comment: I'll agree here with @joshuanapoli 

If I were you, I'd take out the session completely out since a pure REST implementation dictates 0 session awareness.

To answer your question, the user preferences should come to you in your subsequent request rather than you trying to remember it. If it's something that needs to be persisted over with the application, just store them in your models.

Comment: Thanks Josh and Jas for the advice, i'll try to do it that way instead.